# Stuck with validating text in my dentist appointment system

Tags: c++

I have a dentist appointment system that I am making for a school project and we have to take patients details and make appointments. I am trying to validate the input for things like presence checks, range checks, etc. I started with a presence check on the appointment number on the new appointment function(int newApp()) but I am getting these errors pic. I think it is because it is a 2D array and I am not declaring it correctly however I'm unsure.

Sorry if the annotation isn't very good, I believe that comes with time. Also I am using c++ builder 6. Thanks in advance.

Edit - Less code.

```
//includes
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <clx.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <printers.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop

// Customer file definitions
char FileName1[200]="PatientFile";
typedef struct tag_cr{
        char patNo[4];
        char patFName[15];
        char patSName[15];
        char patNum[12];
        char patBday[12];
        char patDateJoin[12];
        char addLine1[30];
        char addLine2[30];
        char city[15];
        char postcode[9];
        char flag[2];
} PATIENT_RECORD;
int patNo;
PATIENT_RECORD a_pat;

//Global Variables for sequentialfileaccess
char appFile[200] = "Appointment File";        // Name of data file
char appPatNo[200][4];                         // Patient number in appointment file
char appNo[200][4];                            // Appointment number
char appDay[200][12];                          // Appointment Date
char appTime[200][6];                          // Appointment Time
char appDenName[200][25];                      // Name of the dentist the appointment is with
char appReason[200][30];                       // Reason for appointment
int nai;                                       // Number of appointments as an integer
char nac[4];                                   // Number of apointments as a character array

//Function Declaration
int mainMenu();                                // User Interface

int newApp();                                  // New appointment
int findApp();                                 // Find appointment
int delApp();                                  // Delete appointment
int newPat();                                  // Register a patient
int delPat();                                  // Delete patient record
int updPat();                                  // Update patient record

int reWriteAppFile();                          // Write the appointment file
int readBackAppFile();                         // Read the appointment file
int createEmptyFileV();                        // Verify if the user wants to create empty file for data
int createEmptyFile();                         // Create empty file for data

bool validateAppNo(char *);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int newApp()
            {
            int compare;
            cout<< "\nAdd a new appointment";
            cout << "\nEnter patient number ";
            cin>>patNo;
            ifstream fin(FileName1, ios::binary);
            fin.seekg(patNo * sizeof (a_pat));
            fin.read((char*)&a_pat,sizeof(a_pat));
            fin.close();
            compare = strcmpi(a_pat.flag, "0");
            if(compare != 0)
            {
                    readBackAppFile();
                    cin.get();

                    cout << "\nEnter the appointment number ";
                    cin.getline(appNo[nai], sizeof(appNo));
                    while(validateAppNo(appNo[nai]) == false)
                    {
                            cout << "\nPlease enter a valid appointment number";
                            cin.getline(appNo[nai], sizeof(appNo));
                    }
                    cout << "\nEnter the date of the appointment ";
                    cin.getline(appDay[nai], sizeof(appDay));
                    cout << "\nEnter the time of the appointment ";
                    cin.getline(appTime[nai], sizeof(appTime));
                    cout << "\nEnter the dentists name ";
                    cin.getline(appDenName[nai], sizeof(appDenName));
                    cout << "\nAppointment reason ";
                    cin.getline(appReason[nai], sizeof(appReason));
                    sprintf(appPatNo[nai], "%d", patNo);
                    nai=nai+1;
                    itoa(nai, nac, 10);
                    reWriteAppFile();
            }  else  {
             cout << "\nNo patient found";
            }
            return 0;
            }

            bool validateAppNo(appNo[nai])
            {
                    bool status = false;
                    if(appNo != NULL)
                    {
                            status = true;
                    }
                    return status;
            }
```

Comment: Wow that is quite a bit of code. Too much, in fact. Post a minimal amount to repro the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: Oh right sorry, you can probably tell I'm new here and in a different post someone told me to post all my code

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays are subject to buffer overrun issues.

Comment: At first glance I don't see any assignment your index variable 'nai`

Comment: @JohnT Who told you to post all your code? Have you taken the [tour], or looked through [help]? You are asked to provide [mcve], not the whole code. In addition, what's with `char` arrays? What's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: You should leave this class and attend one that teaches correct and modern C++.  For example, you don't need `typedef struct` in C++.  Also, the header files `fstream.h` and `iostream.h` are outdated, the correct forms are `fstream` and `iostream`, without the suffixes.

Comment: You should move the `clrscr()` from each case and place it before the `switch` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought this was the case, we have a teacher who doesn't want to change there ways. However I cannot leave this class as I am 16 y/o and have to be in full time education with no other choice

Comment: I don't see any functions or statements that validate the User's input.

Comment: Who cares. There's a distinct difference between using a language for a cs/programming class and *learning* a language. Most early classes are not *language* classes yet many people confuse them as such.

Comment: Your implementation of `bool validateAppNo(appNo[nai])` should look like this: `bool validateAppNo(char* val)` and then use the param in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to validate user input.

My personal style is to use one entry one return, implementing success with a bool variable:

```
bool Is_Valid(const tag_cr& record)
{
  bool is_valid = true;
  if (strlen(record.patNo) == 0)
  {
    is_valid = false;
  }
  if (is_valid && (strlen(record.patFName) == 0)
  {
    is_valid = false;
  }
  // And so on...
  return is_valid;
}
```

A more helpful function would return an error text explaining why the record is invalid:

```
bool Is_Valid(const tag_cr& record, std::string& reason)
{
  bool is_valid = true;
  if (strlen(record.patNo) == 0)
  {
    reason = "patNo field is empty";
    is_valid = false;
  }
  if (is_valid && (strlen(record.patFName) == 0)
  {
    reason = "patFName";
    is_valid = false;
  }

  // And so on...
  return is_valid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems very helpful however I don't know how to implement this into my code in c++. I will go and research, thanks for your help.